# 960gs alpha and omega classes ignored in ≤IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, 960.gs

http://templesmc.staging.wpengine.com/tutv/

In parts of my site where I am using the `alpha` and `omega` classes for nested grid `div`s, Internet Explorer 8 and below do not seem to acknowledge the existence of these classes. In IE's inspector, it shows the original grid margins of 10px in place without being overridden by `alpha`/`omega` classes.

This breaks the layout by leaving an extra 10px of margin.

I've searched all over – I'm aware of the IE8 top margin bug, but I've seen nothing about problems with left and right margins.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in css, the classes alpha and omega uses nth-child that not works in IE8 and below : 
`.alpha, .has-taxonomy-show.singular #content .video-sidebar .video-section .video-item:nth-child(even)`

```
.omega, .has-taxonomy-show.singular #content .video-sidebar .video-section .video-item:nth-child(odd)
```

you should do this with JQuery just for IE8<

Comment: That's it! I would have thought that the two being grouped together wouldn't affect IE8's understanding entirely – I expected it would still at least respect the classes on their own. Time to do some reading about this. Thanks very much.